# How to display a warning message before leaving site by clicking on tab in chrome?

Tags: javascript, function, tabs

I am trying to warn the user before closing the tab. I search on many places for the right code but It seems that it doesn't work in chrome.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

In IE it works fine. I don't need to display any custom message. I just need to warn the user that they will leave the site. Any idea why this doesn't work? Is there any other way to force the browser to display warning before leaving site?

EDITED: I use Google Chrome version 74.0.3729.169

[image]

Comment: Has your tab received a [user gesture](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808) before closing? Seems also that you [can't set your own dialog message](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `confirm()` function:

```
function confirmExit(e) {
  if (!confirm("You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still able to leave the site without any warning. It looks like it has a problem with window.onbeforeunload

Comment: I added animated gif to demonstrate that the code still doesn't display any warning before closing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to [@barbsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7404943/barbsan). The link that he provided contains the solution.

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
 });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeUnloadEvent